# ASCII-art logic gate diagram

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

I challenge you to write a code to make an (extended) ASCII-art logic gate diagram for the sum of products form of an equation.

Use the following notation to represent gates:

AND

```
    INPUT───|&&
            |&&───OUTPUT
    INPUT───|&&
```

OR

```
    INPUT───|OR
            |OR───OUTPUT
    INPUT───|OR
```

Gates with more than 2 inputs

```
    INPUT───|OR
            |OR
    INPUT───|OR───OUTPUT
            |OR
    INPUT───|OR
```

NOT

```
    INPUT───│>o───OUTPUT
```

#### Character set

Note that `│` is not an ASCII pipe sign but a [box-drawing character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). Use box-drawing characters such as `─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘` for connections.

#### Example

Input

```
    A'*B'+B*C
```

Output

```
    A────│>o────│&&
                │&&─────┐
    B────│>o────│&&     └│OR
                         │OR─────A*B+B*C
    B───────────│&&     ┌│OR
                │&&─────┘
    C───────────│&&
```

#### Winner

The winner is the answer with the most up-votes in 5 days

Comment: There are only 95 printable ASCII characters, and they don't include any of these: `─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘`. I think you're referring to the [MS-DOS character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). Also, shouldn't your example have a single `B` input split between the two AND gates? And can we assume that there will be no need for wires to cross over anywhere?

Comment: I love how you say "STRICTLY an ASCII art" and require us to use a non-ASCII character set.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I think there are 128 ASCII characters and 256 after extension of ascii chart visit here  http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: No, he refers to some [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) characters. I've edited the question to clarify that. Extended ASCII includes all seven-bit ASCII characters, as well as some other characters.

Comment: @ProgramFOX He seems to refer to [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Comment: @mniip: The question poster took his image from the "Extended ASCII Codes" of http://www.asciitable.com/ so I'm pretty sure that he refers to Extended ASCII.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I don't know what "extended ascii" is, but it looks quite similar to CP437, with all respective consequences

Comment: @mniip: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) says: "The term extended ASCII (or high ASCII) describes eight-bit or larger character encodings that include the standard seven-bit ASCII characters as well as others." And you can see all those other characters on http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @ProgramFOX, if you read the sentence immediately after the one you've quoted, you'll see that your edit makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Ok, I've changed it into CP437.

Comment: Given the requirement to use box-drawing characters, it seems odd that you're making connections as `─│` rather than `─┤`.

Comment: Can you even use CP437 on a Mac?

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre, there's probably *some* Unicode font with U25xx support.

Comment: Note that you can have pretty diagrams running this javascript code on this page : `javascript:$('code').css({display:'block',lineHeight:'1em'})`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage There can be multiple inputs for one variable refer to the diagram on page-5 here---http://seattlecentral.edu/faculty/mat119/text/LogicGates.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## C++11

*Done at last.* And it only took me most of the day.

Before I list the code and sample output, some quick notes:

#### Things this program does support

- Any number of terms, each with any number of inputs
- Reusing inputs
- Omitting AND/OR gate representation when only one input would be present
- Use of both codepage 437 line-drawing characters and 7-bit ASCII-friendly characters (use -DCP437 or whatever your compiler's equivalent is for codepage 437 support)

#### Things this program does not support

- Grouping with parentheses (because, seriously?)
- Multiple NOTing
- Any whitespace that isn't a plain ASCII space
- Proper golfification (although I did remove all the comments in spirit)
- Sane coding practices
- Making eye contact with the input parsing code
- Portable, Unicode line-drawing characters. I couldn't support Unicode because the rendering logic relies on being able to draw "down" a two-dimensional `char` buffer.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <valarray>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(const string str, const string delim)
{
    vector<string> v;

    set<char> d;
    for (char c : delim) d.insert(c);

    string current {};
    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (d.find(c) != d.end())
        {
            v.push_back(current);
            current = "";
        }
        else
        {
            current += c;
        }
    }
    v.push_back(current);

    return v;
}

using Input = string;
struct TermInput
{
    Input name;
    int ypos;
    bool neg;
};
using Term = vector<TermInput>;
using Expr = vector<Term>;

#ifdef CP437
constexpr char VERT    = '\xB3';
constexpr char HORIZ   = '\xC4';
constexpr char RBRANCH = '\xC3';
constexpr char LUP     = '\xD9';
constexpr char LDOWN   = '\xBF';
constexpr char RUP     = '\xC0';
constexpr char RDOWN   = '\xDA';
#else
constexpr char VERT    = '|';
constexpr char HORIZ   = '-';
constexpr char RBRANCH = '}';
constexpr char LUP     = '\'';
constexpr char LDOWN   = '.';
constexpr char RUP     = '`';
constexpr char RDOWN   = ',';
#endif

string repeat(string s, int n)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ss << s;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
string repeat(char c, int n)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ss << c;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

enum class Direction
{
    RIGHT,
    DOWN
};

void matrixPut(char *matrix, int h, int w, int x, int y, const string s, Direction dir)
{
    if (x >= w || y >= h)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "matrixPut: point (" << x << ", " << y << ") out of matrix bounds!";
        throw new out_of_range(ss.str());
    }

    char *ins = matrix + (y * w) + x;
    char *end = matrix + (h * w);
    for (char c : s)
    {
        if (ins >= end) break;
        *ins = c;

        if (dir==Direction::RIGHT)
        {
            ins++;
        }
        else
        {
            ins += w;
        }
    }
}

void matrixPrint(char *matrix, int h, int w)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (h * w); i++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i];
        if ((i+1)%w == 0) cout << endl;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string expression;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter expression:" << endl;
        getline(cin, expression);
    }
    else
    {
        expression = argv[1];
    }

    expression.erase(remove(expression.begin(), expression.end(), ' '), expression.end());

    Expr expr {};
    auto inputs = set<Input>();
    auto termInputs = multimap<Input, TermInput>();

    int inputYPos = 0;

    auto e = split(expression, "+");
    for (string term : e)
    {
        Term currTerm {};

        auto t = split(term, "*");
        for (string in : t)
        {
            bool neg = false;
            if (in.back() == '\'')
            {
                in.pop_back();
                neg = true;
            }

            Input currInput {in};
            inputs.insert(currInput);

            TermInput ti {currInput, inputYPos, neg};
            currTerm.push_back(ti);

            termInputs.insert(pair<Input, TermInput>{in, ti});
            inputYPos++;
        }

        expr.push_back(currTerm);
        inputYPos++;
    }


    int height = inputs.size() + termInputs.size() + expr.size() - 1;

    int width = 0;

    width += max_element(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), [](Input a, Input b){ return a.length() < b.length(); })->length() + 2;
    int inputWidth = width;
    width += inputs.size()*2;

    int notAndStart = width;

    width += 7;
    width += expr.size()+1;

    int orStart = width;

    width += 4;

    width += 4;

    width += expression.length();

    char matrix[height * width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++) matrix[i] = ' ';
    
    int  baseY = inputs.size();

    {
        int x = width - 4 - expression.length();
        int y = baseY + ((height-baseY) / 2);
        matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x, y, repeat(HORIZ, 4) + expression, Direction::RIGHT);
    }

    {
        int x = orStart;
        int y = baseY + (height-baseY)/2 - expr.size()/2;

        if (expr.size() == 1)
        {
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x, y, repeat(HORIZ, 4), Direction::RIGHT);
        }
        else {
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x  , y, repeat(HORIZ, expr.size()), Direction::DOWN);
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+1, y, repeat(VERT , expr.size()), Direction::DOWN);
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+2, y, repeat('O'  , expr.size()), Direction::DOWN);
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+3, y, repeat('R'  , expr.size()), Direction::DOWN);
        }
    }

    {
        int x = notAndStart;
        int y = baseY;
        for (Term t : expr)
        {
            string layer[7];
            for (TermInput ti : t)
            {
                layer[0] += HORIZ;
                layer[1] += (ti.neg ? '>' : HORIZ);
                layer[2] += (ti.neg ? 'o' : HORIZ);
                layer[3] += HORIZ;
                layer[4] += (t.size() > 1 ? VERT : HORIZ);
                layer[5] += (t.size() > 1 ? '&' : HORIZ);
                layer[6] += (t.size() > 1 ? '&' : HORIZ);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+i, y, layer[i], Direction::DOWN);
            }

            y += t.size() + 1;
        }
    }

    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for (Input i : inputs)
        {
            string str = i + ": ";
            str += repeat(HORIZ, inputWidth - str.length());

            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x, y, str, Direction::RIGHT);
            
            y++;
        }
    }

    {
        int x = inputWidth;
        int num = 0;
        int offset = inputs.size() * 2 - 1;

        for (Input in : inputs)
        {
            int y = 0;
            int len = inputs.size() * 2 - 1;
            auto it = inputs.find(in);
            while (it != inputs.begin())
            {
                it--;
                y++;
                len -= 2;
            }
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x, y, repeat(HORIZ, len) + LDOWN, Direction::RIGHT);
        }

        for (Input in : inputs)
        {
            auto yBreakRange = termInputs.equal_range(in);
            valarray<int> yBreaks(termInputs.count(in));
            int idx = 0;
            for (auto ti = yBreakRange.first; ti != yBreakRange.second; ti++)
            {
                yBreaks[idx++] = baseY + ti->second.ypos;
            }

            for (int y : yBreaks)
            {
                matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+offset, y, repeat(HORIZ, inputs.size()*2 - offset), Direction::RIGHT);
            }

            int y = num + 1;
            int maxBreak = yBreaks.max();
            string branch = repeat(VERT, maxBreak - y + 1);

            for (int i : yBreaks)
            {
                branch[i-y] = RBRANCH;
            }
            branch.back() = RUP;

            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+offset, y, branch, Direction::DOWN);

            offset -= 2;
            num++;
        }
    }
    
    {
        int x = notAndStart + 7;
        int outY = baseY + (height-baseY)/2 - expr.size()/2;
        int breakx = expr.size()/2;

        for (Term t : expr)
        {
            int inY = baseY + (t.front().ypos + t.back().ypos) / 2;
            
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x, inY, repeat(HORIZ, abs(breakx)+1), Direction::RIGHT);
            
            matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+abs(breakx)+1, outY, repeat(HORIZ, expr.size()-abs(breakx)), Direction::RIGHT);
            
            if (inY < outY)
            {
                string branch = LDOWN + repeat(VERT, outY-inY-1) + RUP;
                matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+abs(breakx)+1, inY, branch, Direction::DOWN);
            }
            else if (inY > outY)
            {
                string branch = RDOWN + repeat(VERT, inY-outY-1) + LUP;
                matrixPut(matrix, height, width, x+abs(breakx)+1, outY, branch, Direction::DOWN);
            }
            
            outY++;
            breakx--;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    matrixPrint(matrix, height, width);
    cout << endl;
}
```

### Sample output

```
$ ./gates "A'*B'+B*C"

A: -----.
B: ---. |
C: -. | |
    | | `->o-|&&--.
    | }--->o-|&&  `-|OR
    | |          ,--|OR----A'*B'+B*C
    | `------|&&-'
    `--------|&&

$ ./gates "A*B'*C+B*D'+F*C'*D+G*E*A'+F"

A: -------------.
B: -----------. |
C: ---------. | |
D: -------. | | |
E: -----. | | | |
F: ---. | | | | |
G: -. | | | | | |
    | | | | | | }----|&&
    | | | | | }--->o-|&&---.
    | | | | }--------|&&   |
    | | | | | | |          |
    | | | | | `------|&&--.|
    | | | }------->o-|&&  ||
    | | | | |   |         |`---|OR
    | }--------------|&&  `----|OR
    | | | | `----->o-|&&-------|OR----A*B'*C+B*D'+F*C'*D+G*E*A'+F
    | | | `----------|&&  ,----|OR
    | | |       |         |,---|OR
    `----------------|&&  ||
      | `------------|&&--'|
      |         `->o-|&&   |
      |                    |
      `--------------------'
```

### Sample output (with CP437 enabled)

```
A: ─────────────┐
B: ───────────┐ │
C: ─────────┐ │ │
D: ───────┐ │ │ │
E: ─────┐ │ │ │ │
F: ───┐ │ │ │ │ │
G: ─┐ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├────│&&
    │ │ │ │ │ ├───>o─│&&───┐
    │ │ │ │ ├────────│&&   │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │          │
    │ │ │ │ │ └──────│&&──┐│
    │ │ │ ├───────>o─│&&  ││
    │ │ │ │ │   │         │└───│OR
    │ ├──────────────│&&  └────│OR
    │ │ │ │ └─────>o─│&&───────│OR────A*B'*C+B*D'+F*C'*D+G*E*A'+F
    │ │ │ └──────────│&&  ┌────│OR
    │ │ │       │         │┌───│OR
    └────────────────│&&  ││
      │ └────────────│&&──┘│
      │         └─>o─│&&   │
      │                    │
      └────────────────────┘
```

Comment: +10 for sheer dogged determination :-)

Comment: That is not the output I wanted but, +1 for your hard-work(personally, I appreciate it).Also mention your language!

Comment: Kudos. This is very nice, CP437 or not.

Comment: I made a few edits to the post (not the code) based on the feedback above. I also got MinGW to work on my system so I could build it with native CP437 support, so I added some sample output form that.

Comment: On line 202 I get a compiling error in VisualExpress: int height and int width: Expression must have a constant value. Also you were missing `#include <vector>`

Comment: Oh, I fixed it by making the matrix a pointer with `char * matrix = new char[height * width];`

Answer (score 5):

## C++

Whew ! Done in 1 day 12 hrs!!!
This code handles array only

### INPUT (TYPES)

- Only SOP(sum of products) form.
- Only addition of terms with two variables multiplying

  ```
  EXAMPLES :-

      A*B'+B*A+C*D  

      X*Y+Z'*A'*V*D+B*G+C'*A'
  ```
- Can handle any number of terms,variables.

  #### **CODE :-**

  ```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
  int i,j,k,l,m=0;
  char arr[80][80],expr[45];
  cout<<"enter the SOP(Sum Of products) expression : ";
  cin>>expr;
  cout<<"\n\n";
  for(i=0;expr[i]!='\0';i++)
  if(expr[i]=='*')m++;
  for(i=0;i<80;i++)
      for(j=0;j<80;j++)
          arr[i][j]=' ';
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80,expr[j]!='\0';j++)
  {
      if(expr[j]<=90&&expr[j]>=65||expr[j]<=122&&expr[j]>=97)
      {
          arr[i][0]=expr[j];
          i+=2;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=1;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j-1]<=90&&arr[i][j-1]>=65||arr[i][j-1]<=122&&arr[i][j-1]>=97)
      {
          for(k=0;k<7;k++)
              arr[i][j+k]=196;
          arr[i][j+k]=180;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j]==(char)180&&arr[i][j+1]==' ')
      {
          arr[i][j+1]=38;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0,k=1;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i-1][j]==(char)180&&arr[i+1][j]==(char)180)
      {
          if(arr[i-1][j+1]==(char)38&&arr[i+1][j+1]==(char)38&&k)
          {
              arr[i][j]=179;arr[i][j+1]=38;
              for(l=2;l<4;l++)
              {
                  arr[i][j+l]=196;
              }
              k--;
          }
          else if(k==0)
          {
              k=1;
          }
      }
  }
  l=m;
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j-1]==(char)196&&arr[i][j+1]==' '&&arr[i][j-2]==(char)38)
          {
          if(arr[i+3][j-2]==(char)38)
          {
              for(k=0;k<l;k++)
                  arr[i][j+k]=(char)196;
              arr[i][j+k-1]=(char)191;

              l--;
          }
          else
          {
              for(k=0;k<m;k++)
              arr[i][j+k]=(char)196;
          }
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0,k=1;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j]==(char)191&&arr[i][j-1]==(char)196)
      {
          for(;arr[i+k][j]==' ';k++)
          {
              arr[i+k][j]=(char)179;
          }
      k=1;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j]==(char)179&&arr[i][j-3]==(char)38&&arr[i+1][j]==(char)196)
      {
          arr[i][j]=(char)192;
          for(k=1;arr[i-k][j+k]==(char)179;k++)
          {
              arr[i-k][j+k]=(char)192;
          }
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j-1]==(char)192)
      {
          for(k=0;arr[i][j+k]!=' ';k++)
              arr[i][j+k]=(char)196;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j-1]==(char)192&&arr[i][j]==' '||arr[i][j-1]==(char)196&&arr[i][j]==' ')
      {
          arr[i][j]=(char)180;
          arr[i][j+1]='O';
          arr[i][j+2]='R';
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j-1]=='R'&&arr[i+1][j-1]==' ')
      {
          for(k=0;k<3;k++)
              arr[i][j+k]=(char)196;
          j+=k;
          for(k=0;expr[k]!='\0';k++)
          {
              arr[i][j+k]=expr[k];
          }
      }
  }
  for(i=0,k=0;i<80,expr[k]!='\0';k++)
  {
      if((expr[k]<='z'&&expr[k]>='a'||expr[k]<='Z'&&expr[k]>='A'))
      {
          if(expr[k+1]=='\'')
              arr[i][1]='\'';
          i+=2;
      }
  }
  for(i=0,j=0;i<80;j++)
  {
      if(j==80){i++;j=0;}
      if(arr[i][j]=='\''&&arr[i][j+1]==(char)196)
      {
          arr[i][j+3]=(char)180;
          arr[i][j+4]=(char)62;
          arr[i][j+5]='o';
      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<35;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<80;j++)
          cout<<arr[i][j];
      cout<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
  }
  ```

### OUTPUT

[image]